# Not sure how to manage my data in an observableArray for updating

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, observable

I'm just starting to play around with KO as I want to bring it into an upcoming project.  In my spare time I've been playing with a web service at work, this has basically been starting off with doing something with the data, then doing something else.  So first I just returned a list of drug names.  OK, let's add a count of the returned results.  OK, let's populate the individual drug details in a modal.  OK, let's edit a drug name.  No real rhyme or reason, just coming up with stuff and playing around with KO.

I'm at the point where I'm not sure how to really manage my data so it gets updated everywhere.  I've made a screenshot that walks you through what I have and illustrates the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmAB6.jpg

1. Get my search results by clicking on the "y" button.  I then select
   the "Yasmin 28" drug
2. I get the detail view for that drug in a modal window
3. I edit the drug name and click the "save" button
4. The drug name is updated in the modal window
5. I "cheat" and update the drug name in the search results by just
   crawling that part of the DOM and replacing the old drug name with
   the new drug name.

Problem with this is, it isn't taking advantage of the observable nature of KO...If I were to close the modal and click on the "Yasmin 28" drug link again, the modal would show "Yasmin 28" not what I just changed it to ("something wonderful").

I'm not quite sure how to track if a property changes in my observableArray.  I made two observableArrays, one holds the list of drug names for the search results, the other holds the details of the drug.  I also made an observable for the current drug name.

Can someone explain what I need to do to track my drug name everywhere?  I've included the code below as well as the JSON that I'm working with at the very bottom.

```
<div id="shell">
    <button class="load" value="j">j</button>
    <button class="load" value="k">k</button>
    <button class="load" value="x">x</button>
    <button class="load" value="y">y</button>
    <button class="load" value="z">z</button>
    <p id="loading"><img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/img/spinner.gif"/></p>

    <h3 data-bind="visible: drugList().length > 0"><span data-bind="text: count" class="count"></span> records returned</h3>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: drugList">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: drugName" class="results_drug_name"></span>
            <a data-bind="click: $root.showDetails" href="#" class="show">show details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- start modal: drug details -->
<div id="dialog" data-bind="jqDialog: {autoOpen: false, title: drugName}">
    <p id="dialog_save_message" class="message_success">Changes saved successfully!!!!!!!!</p>

    <table data-bind="foreach: drugListDetails" class="table" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">pdlId</th>
            <td data-bind="text: pdlId"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">drugName</th>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: $root.drugName" class="readonly"></span>
                <input id="edit_drugname" class="edit_textfield" type="text" value="" size="35" />
                <button data-bind="click: $root.editSave" class="edit_buttons save">Save</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.editCancel" class="edit_buttons cancel">Cancel</button>
                <ul class="detail_actions">
                    <li><a data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" class="edit">edit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">dosageFormDesc</th>
            <td data-bind="text: dosageFormDesc"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">strength</th>
            <td data-bind="text: strength"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">activeIngredient</th>
            <td data-bind="text: activeIngredient"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">tier</th>
            <td data-bind="text: tier"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">ancillaryCharge</th>
            <td data-bind="text: ancillaryCharge"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">preauthCode</th>
            <td data-bind="text: preauthCode"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">quantityLimit</th>
            <td data-bind="text: quantityLimit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">prefAlternative</th>
            <td data-bind="text: prefAlternative"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">specialtyDrug</th>
            <td data-bind="text: specialtyDrug"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">partbCob</th>
            <td data-bind="text: partbCob"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">drugClassGroupId</th>
            <td data-bind="text: drugClassGroupId"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">drugClassId</th>
            <td data-bind="text: drugClassId"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">drugClass</th>
            <td data-bind="text: drugClass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">genericInd</th>
            <td data-bind="text: genericInd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">tip</th>
            <td data-bind="text: tip"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- end modal: drug details -->

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.load').click(function() {
        var $letter = $(this).attr('value');

        //show spinner
        $('#loading').show();

        //load in drug list data
        $.getJSON('/PreferredDrugList/service/preferredDrugs/' + $letter, function(data) {
            //hide spinner
            $('#loading').hide();

            //replace drugList observableArray data
            //preferredDrugs is an array of objects, each elem is an individual drug
            myViewModel.drugList(data.preferredDrugs);

            //replace count observable data
            myViewModel.count(data.count);
        });//end getJSON
    });//end click

    //setup modal dialog options
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width:850,
        height:500
    });

});//end ondomready

//custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI dialog
ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
    init: function(element) {
       ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());

        if (options) {
            $(element).dialog(options);
        }           
    }
};

var myViewModel = {
    count:                ko.observable(),        //# of records returned
    drugList:            ko.observableArray(),    //list of drug names - an array of objects
    drugListDetails:    ko.observableArray(),    //list of individual drug details
    drugName:            ko.observable(),        //current drug name

    //show drug details in modal
    //func gets passed the current observableArray elem (the individual drug info we clicked on, this is an object)
    showDetails: function(obj) {
        //replace current drug name observable data
        myViewModel.drugName(obj.drugName);

        //replace drugListDetails observableArray data, otherwise we'll append data to the modal
        myViewModel.drugListDetails([]);

        //push individual drug info to details observableArray
        myViewModel.drugListDetails.push(obj);

        //show dialog
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');

        return false;
    },

    //edit drug from modal
    edit: function(obj) {
        var $edit         = $('#dialog').find('td .edit'),
            $currentTD    = $edit.closest('td');

        $currentTD.addClass('editing');
        $currentTD.find('.readonly').hide();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_textfield').show().select();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_buttons').show();

        return false;
    },

    //save an edit
    editSave: function(obj) {
        alert('TODO save back to the server');

        var $saveBtn    = $('#dialog').find('td .save'),
            $currentTD    = $saveBtn.closest('td'),
            newDrugName = $('#edit_drugname').val(),
            $dialog_save_message = $('#dialog_save_message');

        //save new drug name to observable
        myViewModel.drugName(newDrugName);

        $currentTD.removeClass('editing');
        $currentTD.find('.readonly').show();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_textfield').hide();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_buttons').hide();

        $dialog_save_message.slideDown('slow', function() {
            //animation complete
            setTimeout(function() {
                $dialog_save_message.slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        });

        //cheat and update search results list with new drug name
        $('.results_drug_name').each(function(index, elem) {
            var $text = $(this).text();

            if ($text === obj.drugName) {
                $(this).text(newDrugName).addClass('edited');
            }
        });
    },

    //cancel an edit
    editCancel: function(obj) {
        var $cancelBtn     = $('#dialog').find('td .cancel'),
            $currentTD    = $cancelBtn.closest('td');

        $currentTD.removeClass('editing');
        $currentTD.find('.readonly').show();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_textfield').hide();
        $currentTD.find('.edit_buttons').hide();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

<!--what's returned from the web service-->
<pre>
{
    "preferredDrugs": [(8)
        {
            "pdlId": 8090,
            "drugName": "y-cof-dmx",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Liquid",
            "strength": "4MG/5ML; 15MG/5ML; 7.5MG/5ML",
            "activeIngredient": "BROMPHENIRAMINE MALEATE; DEXTROMETHORPHAN HYDROBROMIDE; PHENYLEPHRINE HYDROCHLORIDE",
            "tier": "OTC",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": null,
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 74,
            "drugClassId": 152,
            "drugClass": "Respiratory Tract Agents » Antitussives",
            "genericInd": "1",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 13417,
            "drugName": "YASMIN 28",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Tablet",
            "strength": "3MG; 0.03MG",
            "activeIngredient": "DROSPIRENONE; ETHINYL ESTRADIOL",
            "tier": "3",
            "ancillaryCharge": "AC",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": "28.0 tabs each 28 days",
            "prefAlternative": "ethinyl estradiol/drospirenone",
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 3,
            "drugClassId": 200,
            "drugClass": "Hormones and Synthetic Substitutes » Contraceptives",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 24765,
            "drugName": "YAZ",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Tablet",
            "strength": "3MG; 0.02MG",
            "activeIngredient": "DROSPIRENONE; ETHINYL ESTRADIOL",
            "tier": "3",
            "ancillaryCharge": "AC",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": "28.0 tabs each 28 days",
            "prefAlternative": "ethinyl estradiol/drospirenone",
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 3,
            "drugClassId": 200,
            "drugClass": "Hormones and Synthetic Substitutes » Contraceptives",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 2252,
            "drugName": "YERVOY",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Solution",
            "strength": "50MG/10ML",
            "activeIngredient": "IPILIMUMAB",
            "tier": "NC",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": null,
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 115,
            "drugClassId": 1,
            "drugClass": "Antineoplastic Agents",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 20993,
            "drugName": "YERVOY",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Solution",
            "strength": "200MG/40ML",
            "activeIngredient": "IPILIMUMAB",
            "tier": "NC",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": null,
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 115,
            "drugClassId": 1,
            "drugClass": "Antineoplastic Agents",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 564,
            "drugName": "YF-VAX",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Injection",
            "strength": "0",
            "activeIngredient": "YELLOW FEVER VACCINE",
            "tier": "NC",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": null,
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 79,
            "drugClassId": 284,
            "drugClass": "Serums, Toxoids and Vaccines » Vaccines",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 8910,
            "drugName": "yodefan-nf chest congestion",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Liquid",
            "strength": "200MG/5ML",
            "activeIngredient": "GUAIFENESIN",
            "tier": "OTC",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": null,
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 84,
            "drugClassId": 155,
            "drugClass": "Respiratory Tract Agents » Expectorants",
            "genericInd": "1",
            "tip": " "
        },-
        {
            "pdlId": 13101,
            "drugName": "YODOXIN",
            "dosageFormDesc": "Tablet",
            "strength": "650MG",
            "activeIngredient": "IODOQUINOL",
            "tier": "3",
            "ancillaryCharge": "NA",
            "preauthCode": " ",
            "quantityLimit": " ",
            "prefAlternative": "iodoquinol",
            "specialtyDrug": " ",
            "partbCob": " ",
            "drugClassGroupId": 164,
            "drugClassId": 277,
            "drugClass": "Anti-infective Agents » Antiprotozoals",
            "genericInd": "0",
            "tip": " "
        }-
    ],-
    "count": 8
}   
</pre>

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you use two different drug lists? Why not just use the same list for both?

Comment: That's what I can't figure out - how to work with just one observableArray?  When I load the JSON data from the server, I'm working with: myViewModel.drugList(data.preferredDrugs); (an array of objects to iterate over with foreach)  How would I make it work with: myViewModel.drugList(data); which is a higher level in my JSON structure?  I can't seem to drill down into the preferredDrugs array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, remove the `drugListDetails` array as it causes confusion by holding a duplicate of your data.

**Second**, use `ko.mapping.fromJS` and `ko.mapping.toJS` to map your `data.preferredDrugs` to and from an observable array. This will allow `knockout` to track the changes in the GUI for every element of the array. Documentation for these can be found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

You can also do the mapping manually if you do not want to use the `mapping` plugin.

**Third**, add a new `showDetails` element to each entry in your `data.preferredDrugs` array that defaults to `false`. This will be used in the next step to determine if the dialog should be shown or not. The `showDetails` element will need to be toggled when the existing `$root.showDetails` is called.

**Fourth**, modify the dialog `div` to use the `drugList` array and bind its `visible` value to the `showDetails` value of each drug element. This will create multiple hidden dialogs, so you may want to change the `id` value of each.

Comment: Looking into the mapping plugin now.  I can get that working with static data, but it doesn't seem to work when I load in json from the server.  Thanks for the heads up for that plugin, looks like what I need.